# Jasmine: Cannot set isMultiple of undefined

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm getting an error in my test:

```
Failed: Cannot set property 'isMultiple' of undefined
```

My test script is pretty standard - it looks liek this:

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DropdownTypeaheadControlComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.multipleStringSeperator = '|';
    component.isMultiple = true;

    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  // This test fails.
  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

In my component there is a property called isMultiple set. However, I don't understand why my component is `undefined`.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I fixed it. For me it was because an Input parameter had a property isMultiple, and the input parameter was undefined. So all I had to do was to define the property in the `beforeEach()` section:

```
component.question = {
    isMultiple: false
}
```

Thanks for all your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with

```
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DropdownTypeaheadControlComponent);
component = fixture.componentInstance;
fixture.detectChanges();

component.multipleStringSeperator = '|';
component.isMultiple = true;
```

???

Answer (score 0):

You should move all the assignments of the component inside the `it` block.

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DropdownTypeaheadControlComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  // Test should not fail now :)
  it('should be created', () => {
    fixture.componentInstance.multipleStringSeperator = '|';
    fixture.componentInstance.isMultiple = true;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

Comment: I doubt that your solution is correct, because there is no ´component.componentInstance´ property.

Comment: Oops sorry, it was a mistake. It should have been `fixture.componentInstance`. I updated the answer.